# How can I print an old revision of a Google Document without restoring it?

Tags: google-drive

I want to print an old revision of a Google Document (drawing) without restoring it. Is there any way to do so?

This video shows that if I select the old revision and try to print it, it will print the most recent revision instead: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vsBjcSK7dJM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to print an old revision of a Google Document (drawing) without restoring it.